# How to i disguise my phone as a tablet/computer?

Tags: wifi, android, access-control, phone

Where I work, the wifi blocks phones. So currently, when I use my phone to help me complete my work it uses almost all of my "data". I can't afford a tablet or a larger data package.

Is there any way to disguise my phone as a tablet/computer? I've looked online but there doesn't seem to be any solution as of yet. I have an Android phone running Marshmallow.

Comment: You need to check with IT to determine exactly what their blocking criteria is.  If it's based on the MAC, you could cheat it.

Comment: They might not be blocking it but simply they haven't figured out how to setup security on it so it works with only Windows and Macs where you have private keys for WPA2 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

More manageable than link layer addresses is filtering on browser user agent, or something like p0f IIRC. You don't specify how/what is blocked. If it is browsing, go to about:config in firefox/similar, and create a new key called general.useragent.override . Try a value like 'Mozilla/1.0' - other user agent strings can be found with google. If it is something like p0f (passive OS fingerprinting) it can't be easily bypassed on a phone. Perhaps OpenVPN. If it is mac address you will need to root your phone (perhaps towelroot), install supersu, and either change it with `ifconfig $radio hw ether 00:de:ad:be:ef:00` or some app from the play store. That is a mess. Don't root your device unless you are ok with a voided warranty.